# RewriteRule htaccess article and pagination querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to apply some rewrite rules in my `htaccess`, I have looked into several available articles here on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but I still couldn't solve all problems.

Ugly URL: `www.example.com/index.php?p=page&article_id=14&currentpage=2`

SEO URL : `www.example.com/page/14/2`

Where `p` is the dynamic page name, `article_id` is the article id obviously and `currentpage` is the pagination query string.

My current rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The previously mentioned rule works perfectly in this case:

Ugly URL: `www.example.com/index.php?p=page`

SEO URL : `www.example.com/page`

But what about when I have the `article_id` and the `currentpage` in some cases?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So something like:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=page&article_id=$1&currentpage=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To route that specific case?

Or route it in PHP, a very simple route for the `.htaccess` you currently have to fit is something like:

```
$p = strtolower($_GET['p']);
$params = explode('/', $p);
if(!is_array($params)) {
    $func = $params;
} else {
    $func = array_shift($params);
}

if("page" == $func) {
    if(is_array($params)) {
        $article_id = $params[0];
        $currentpage = isset($params[1]) ? $params[1] : 0;
        //Do something with that info, use what's needed to errorcheck/etc
    } else {
        //default view
    }
}
```

Though, looking into routing would suite you better in my opinion, if all that can be dynamic.  Again, the example shows how you can do it without anything external, bare-bones type of thing, there are tons of classes out there that will do routing as well.

Comment: Jon, all values are dynamic, "page" "14" "2" are just examples

Comment: @mjabado was updating question for the case of them all being dynamic, added a routing example for you. ^^